# str_replace strange behavior

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4

In my codebase I have a line of code, which is triggered through a `cron`

```
const SALE_ORDER_NR = '{{order}}';  
$text = str_replace(self::SALE_ORDER_NR, $order, $text);
```

I am using Magento 1.9;

Here,  $order is of type : `Sales_Model_Order`

$text is not having any substring as `{{order}}`, instead it is :

```
Refund of Rs.150.00 for your order 145004617 has been initiated. Refund may take upto 8-9 days to credit into your bank account.
```

So, the strange behavior is that when I try to run the above code in my local server it passes without any issue.

But when I am trying to run the lines of code via the cron in my `Testing Server`, I get the following errors :

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Dbaux_Sales_Model_Order could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/magento3/app/code/local/Artio/SMSNotifier/Model/Sms/Template.php on line 351
```

Since I am new to the world of magento, it would be really helpful if reason for above behavior can be cleared.

Why is the error being thrown when running the cron, and not when I directly call the observer method from another method.

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: you can not write like this bro!

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel Which part?

Comment: $order is object and you are trying to do str_replace on top of it. that's why you are getting this. Try adding some logs and see what you are missing

Comment: @ArifAhmad yeah, but my problem is that this bug happens only when I am running through a cron, when I execute the method by calling from another method, it doesn't break the flow.

Comment: I got it. But, I would suggest to add a log on $order. You can also do a debug_backtrace to trace how it arrived there. Good luck